# How can I adapt this code to use a single instance instead of creating multiple instances of a service?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am writing a service for sending emails and I would like to send multiple email notifications at the same time. What I currently have is this:

```
    private void SendInstantMailNotification(string notificationId)
    {
        MailMessage? message = null;
        var notifications = _dbContext
                .Notifications
                .Where(x => x.Id.Equals(notificationId))
                .ToList();

        var notification = notifications.First();

       message = notification.Content;

       Smtp.SendMailSync(message, SmtpConfiguration, Smtp.MailTypeEnum.HTML);
    }
```

The last line of the code creates an instance of the "SMTP" service. And for each time I would like to send an email a new instance is created.
How do I achieve this to be only one instance to be created and called multiple times without overloading the system?

This is the constructor:

```
    private readonly NotificationQueueContext _dbContext;

    protected NotificationQueueService(NotificationQueueContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
```

Comment: can you include the `constructor` of the class in your question? I don't see  where the method creates a new instance of `SMTP`

Comment: I added the constructor. What happens when you call a method like the method above? The ``Smtp.SendMailAsync`` method. Doesn't it get instantiated every time this is called?

Comment: still can not find where you have created your `smtp` class. something like this: `SmtpClient Smtp = new SmtpClient("XXX")`

Comment: You can achieve that by using Singleton Design Pattern in C#, look at this link, I hope it will be useful 
https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/singleton-design-pattern/

Comment: There is a dependency on the project which has the Smtp service. I can call it from that dependency. @Amin

Comment: what symptoms are you seeing that makes you think that reusing the same Smtp instance will help with `overloading the system`?

Comment: can't you define this service as a singleton?

Comment: @Jonesopolis well isn't it sufficient that I create the service again and again for each call of the function? I would like to reuse the same service and kind of queue the methods one by one

Comment: The fact that Smtp starts with a capital letter suggests that you are using a static method from some third part library. Please specify which one. As others are noting: How do you know it's creating a new instance, and how do you know it leads to overload?

Comment: BTW: Is it SendMailSync or SendMailAsync? The code says sync and the comments async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you need a mechanism to sequentially run some tasks. So I created a Background service which creates a `SMTP client` once and a `ConcurrentQueue` to hold the mail requests and run them one by one.

This service is going to be active through the whole process of your application so it has `while(TRUE)` in it. and after each email it sends it waits for `500` ms.

If you want to send a mail from other services you just need to call `RegisterMailRequest` to enqueue a mail request.

you should define this service as a `HostedService` like this:
`services.AddHostedService<SequentialJobHandler>();`

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using MimeKit;

namespace Sample
{
    public class SequentialJobHandler : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly string MailServerAddress;
        private readonly int MailServerPort;
        private readonly string AdminEmailAccount;
        private readonly string AdminEmailAccountPass;
        private readonly string MailUser;
        private readonly string MailTitle;
        private ConcurrentQueue<MailRequest> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<MailRequest>();


        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {
                // For demo-purposes, accept all SSL certificates (in case the server supports STARTTLS)
                client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;

                await client.ConnectAsync(MailServerAddress, MailServerPort, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.Auto);

                // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
                await client.AuthenticateAsync(MailUser, AdminEmailAccountPass);


                while (true)
                {
                    MailRequest localValue = null;
                    if (queue.TryDequeue(out localValue))
                    {
                        if (localValue != null)
                        {
                            SendMail(localValue, client);    
                        }
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
                //await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
            }
        }


        private async Task SendMail(MailRequest request, SmtpClient client)
        {
            var message = new MimeMessage();
            message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(MailTitle, AdminEmailAccount));
            message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(request.toUsername,  request.toEmail));
            message.Subject = request.subject;

            message.Body = new TextPart("html")
            {
                Text = request.body
            };
            
            await client.SendAsync(message);
        }


        public void RegisterMailRequest(MailRequest request)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(request);
        }
        
        public class MailRequest
        {
            public string toUsername, toEmail, subject, body;
        }
    }
}
```

hope this helps.